# lodash flatten inner array (part of object) and generate as many object based on array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following Array of Objects. I want to generate as many Objects based on inner 'Y' array length.

```
var arr = [{x:1,y:[1,2]},{x:2,y:[1,2]}];
```

Expected Output as follows

```
var arr = [{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:2},{x:2,y:1},{x:2,y:2}]
```

Code I have tried but i could't

```
arr.forEach(item => {
  return item.y.forEach(inner => {
    return inner;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap()` with nested `map()`. Use `flatMap()` on the main array and inside that use `map()` on `y` property of that object. `return` an object from inner `map()` function whose `y` property will be different and `x` will be the same

```js
var arr = [{x:1,y:[1,2]},{x:2,y:[1,2]}];
const res = arr.flatMap(({x, y}) => y.map(y => ({x, y})));
console.log(res)
```

If you don't understand the `flatMap` below is the version using nested `forEach`

```js
var arr = [{x:1,y:[1,2]},{x:2,y:[1,2]}];
const res = [];
arr.forEach(a => {
  a.y.forEach(y => {
    res.push({x: a.x, y});
  })
})
console.log(res)
```